# How to Find Starting time of consuming data from a kafka topic by the consumer group

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there any API we can use to find the starting time of consumer group started consuming from a Kafka topic?

I am using Kafka Version 0.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka doesn't track this information so there's no API you can query to retrieve this data. However, there's a number of consumer group metrics you can monitor that should enable you to figure this out.

Also monitoring tools like [Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow) should help you find this information.